# php mysql returns only 1 row if using class

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
class SampleClass extends MainClass {

 private $totalOrder;
 //construct goes here

 function get_total_number_of_order($buyerIndex) {
  $totalSum = //sql to get sum of orders
  return $totalSum;
 }

 function fetch_buyer() {

  $qryBuyerInfo = //sql to get buyer info;

  while($rs = $qryBuyerInfo->fetch()) {
   $this->totalOrder = $this->get_total_number_of_order($rs['buyer_index']);

   echo $buyerInfo .'<br>';
   echo $this->totalOrder .'<br>';
  }

 }
```

I'm wondering why I only get 1 record wherein fact my table has at least 20 records. But if I comment out

```
$this->totalOrder = $this->get_total_number_of_order($rs['buyer_index']);
```

I will be able to generate all 20 records. Another thing I tried is to put

```
get_total_number_of_order
```

to other class an every loop, I initiate new class to use

```
get_total_number_of_order
```

function.

Anybody can have any better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue in your code.

```
while($rs = $qryBuyerInfo->fetch()) {
   $this->totalOrder = $this->get_total_number_of_order($rs['buyer_index']);

   echo $buyerInfo .'<br>';
   echo $this->totalOrder .'<br>';
  }
```

with above code, you are only getting 1 record as you are re-writing the data into same object. You need to add this loop data into an array. Something like below:

```
$i=0;
while($rs = $qryBuyerInfo->fetch()) {
   $this->totalOrder[$i] = $this->get_total_number_of_order($rs['buyer_index']);

   echo $buyerInfo .'<br>';
   echo $this->totalOrder[$i] .'<br>';
   $i++;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will check if it works on my current code. ^_^